# I have to do client performance testing..is it we can do using selenium webdriver sampler in Jmeter and what are metrics needs to collected as result

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Requirement is need to do client side Performance testing.

1. Can we do using selenium webdriver sampler in Jmeter for client side Performance testing?
2. What are the metrics needs to be collected in the results?
3. What are the actions need to put in script for client side Performance testing

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes "we" can, [this is what WebDriver Sampler is designed for](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/):

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

   So you should create main load in one (or several) [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) using JMeter's HTTP Request samplers (and at the same time making sure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)) and use a separate Thread Group with 1-2 users with WebDriver Samplers for measuring page loading speed from the client perspective
2. The metrics which are defined in your [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement). If you don't have either of these you can come up with the ones basing on common sense, your application specifics or just take everything available via [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API) and [Web Vitals](https://web.dev/vitals/)
3. You should simulate real life usage of your application by real users so the "actions" needs to be taken from the business use cases.